# Backbone.js issuing GET requests for `model.save()` calls

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a Backbone application in which I am creating a new model and saving it. Here's a snippet of the code, with debugging, in CoffeeScript:

```
newListing = new Listing
console.log "New?", newListing.isNew()
newListing.save creation, {
  wait: true
  success: (model, response) =>
    console.log "SAVED", model
    console.log "RESPONSE", response
}
```

For debugging, I have also overridden `Backbone.sync`:

```
oldSync = Backbone.sync
Backbone.sync = (method, model) ->
  console.log "Syncing:", method, model
  oldSync(arguments...)
```

Usually, this works fine. I get this in the console:

```
New? true
Syncing: create > Listing
SAVED > Listing
RESPONSE > Object
```

And in the Network Inspector I see:

```
listings POST 200 application/json
```

I also see a POST request logged in my (Rails) application log.

However, after creating a few Listings, I start to see the following behavior on the console:

```
New? true
Syncing: create > Listing
SAVED > Listing
RESPONSE [> Object, > Object, > Object, > Object, > Object, > Object]
```

where each `Object` is a Listing already saved in the database. The Network Inspector and my application log also indicate that Backbone performed a GET request to /listings. Furthermore, the `Listing` in the third line that has been "SAVED" is a client-side representation of the listing (without some additional details that the server usually inserts).

I have not been able to find any pattern to this behavior; sometimes, Backbone insists on sending GET after GET, and after a refresh it starts working. Sometimes it acts up until I restart my application server. Happy to explore any suggestions!

[Edit]

Alright, after some sleuthing, it appears that after I call `fetch()` on a `Listings` collection, `Listing#save()` starts doing this. The issue only appears on my laptop, which is running Chrome Dev (v19). On other browsers and older versions of Chrome it works fine.

Comment: At first glance it seems like there are some event bindings that are hanging around as you use the app you are building.  Any chance you could post the code from your views?

Comment: After spending the past three days writing models and collections to speak with our rest service, I've never seen this happen. Do you have a live example?

Comment: +1 for 'sleuthing' :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this is an application specific issue. My guess is that the issue is server side. Perhaps your server side code is returning all of the Listings after a creation rather than just the one that was created. On successful creation your server should respond with 200 OK, and the representation of the created entity in the response body.